# Returning a value from a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, return

```
//... Some annoying getter 
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Integer> result = es.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        //Get some value from the SQL database.
    }
});

return result;
```

Okay, I've looked all over. I need to know how I can make this wait until it finishes retrieving a value from a database to return this.

Comment: If you want to wait until the result is available, what's the point of executing that job in a separate thread, and not in the current thread? Or are you executing several of these jobs concurrently?

Comment: Presumably there is more code in the method.

Comment: @Thilo that's also what I presume, but...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `result.get()` to wait for the task to finish and to retrieve the result.

The API documentation is your friend. Here's the page describing the API of [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).