# Does an instance field of a Java object which is written by a thread and then read by another thread have to be volatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I code in Java8, and I want to use a thread and then catch the result which the thread creates via a mutable object. The code is something like the following:

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MutableString mutableString = new MutableString();

        Thread thread = new Thread(
                () -> mutableString.value = "value_from_another_thread");
        thread.start();
        thread.join();

        assert "value_from_another_thread".equals(mutableString.value);
    }

    private static class MutableString {
        String value; // Does this have to be volatile or should I use AtomicReference instead of MutableString?
    }
}
```

It seems that it works fine on my dev laptop, but is there any possibility where this code doesn't work properly in some environment? Should I use `volatile` for the `value` field or replace the `MutableString` class by `AtomicReference` for safety?

**EDIT:**

What if a `CountDownLatch` was used instead of `thread.join()` ? Does it change something?

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MutableString mutableString = new MutableString();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread(latch, mutableString);

        myThread.start();
        latch.await();

        assert "value_from_another_thread".equals(mutableString.value);
    }

    private static class MyThread extends Thread {

        private final CountDownLatch latch;
        private final MutableString mutableString;

        MyThread(CountDownLatch latch, MutableString mutableString) {
            this.latch = latch;
            this.mutableString = mutableString;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mutableString.value = "value_from_another_thread";
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }

    private static class MutableString {
        String value; // Does this have to be volatile or should I use AtomicReference instead of MutableString?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a happens before relation between calling the thread stopping and the join completing. So the join will see whatever the thread has done. Hence no extra synchronization is needed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4

Using a countdown latch provides similar ordering guarantees.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html
Look for memory consistency effects.

Personally I would not try to be too smart. Unless you are writing very high performant code and you have some tight loop with a volatile write, adding a volatile will not make much performance impact on your application. So I would rather be conservative and add volatile.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do *something*.

`volatile` would be one way, `synchronized` another. Both very low-level. Maybe [`join` also already guarantees this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15124036/14955). I don't want to have to think about this, and you normally don't have to by using the proper higher-level abstractions.

If those were the only options (we were not allowed to do any refactoring at all), I'd say go with `AtomicReference`. It's made for exactly this use-case and gives you more power (such as compare-and-swap).

However: Why have mutable state at all?

Replace the `Runnable` inside your `Thread` with a `Callable<String>` and have it [return its result as a return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28106857/14955).

Comment: +1 for info about `join()` - I didn't know that. What if it was `CountDownLatch` then (question edited) ? Thanks for the other suggestions too

Comment: I don't want to have to think about this, and you normally don't have to by using the proper higher-level abstraction, which in this case is `Callable`.